javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
I am trying to make a Post call to a api using Resteasy version 5.0.4.Final. This is my code below:
package com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment;
import com.jc2.service.client.domobj.ClientDO;
import com.jc2.service.rest.AbstractRestFacade;
import com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment.transform.Transformer;
import com.jc2.service.user.McSecurityContext;
import com.jc2.service.user.McUserService;
import com.jc2.service.user.domobj.McUserDO;
import com.jc2.service.webservice.WebServiceFactory;
import lombok.extern.jbosslog.JBossLog;
import nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.ApiException;
import nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.api.DefaultApi;
import nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.model.WsContactMoment;
import nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.model.WsContactMomentResponse;


import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.UUID;

@Stateless
@JBossLog
public class ContactMomentFacadeBean extends AbstractRestFacade implements        ContactMomentFacade {

@EJB
private WebServiceFactory webServiceFactory;
@EJB
private McUserService mcUserService;
@EJB
private Transformer transformer;


@Override
public void create(McSecurityContext context, ClientDO clientDO, BaseContactMomentDo contactMoment) {

    if (contactMoment == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("contactMoment is null");
    }
    if (contactMoment.getUsernameMcUser() == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("McUser is null");
    }
    if (context.getUsername() == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("username is null");
    }
    try {
        final DefaultApi api = webServiceFactory.getContactMomentApi(bearerToken(context));
        McUserDO mcUser = mcUserService.findMcUser(context.getUsername());
        if (mcUser == null) {
            mcUser = mcUserService.findMcUser(contactMoment.getUsernameMcUser());
        }
        contactMoment.setUsernameMcUser(context.getUsername());
        //TODO remove this null check if not neccessary anymore
        if (contactMoment.getUsernameMcUser() == null) {
            contactMoment.setUsernameMcUser(mcUser.getUserName());
        }
        WsContactMoment wsContactMoment = new WsContactMoment();
        //TODO fix the getContactMomentType issue. it needs a transformer
        if (contactMoment.getContactMomentType() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("contactMomentType is null");
        }

        wsContactMoment.setContactType(transformer.transformContactTypeFromString(contactMoment.getContactMomentType()));
        wsContactMoment.setPublicationType(transformer.transformPublicationType().get(contactMoment.getPublicationType()));
        wsContactMoment.setUsernameMcUser(contactMoment.getUsernameMcUser());
        wsContactMoment.setActive(contactMoment.isActive());
        wsContactMoment.setInfo(contactMoment.getInfo());
        if (contactMoment.getUuid() != null && !contactMoment.getUuid().isEmpty()) {
            wsContactMoment.setUuid(contactMoment.getUuid());
        } else {
            wsContactMoment.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        wsContactMoment.setContactMomentDate(LocalDate.parse(contactMoment.getContactMomentDate().toString()));

        api.createContactMoment(clientDO.getClientNumber(), wsContactMoment);

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

}

The error occurs when trying to post a "contactMoment" in the following line of code.
api.createContactMoment(clientDO.getClientNumber(), wsContactMoment);
and I think the main problem lies in this error. How can I fix this?
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request:     org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-    client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(M    anualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-   client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java   :494)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-   client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)

This is part of the stacktrace, I have searched quite a long time for the solution but couldn't find much about it. If you guys need the full stacktrace I will try to paste it. but it was considered spam so I deleted some stuff from the stacktrace
09:56:37,529 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: Jakarta Enterprise Beans Invocation failed on component ContactMomentFacadeBean for method public abstract void com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment.ContactMomentFacade.create(com.jc2.service.user.McSecurityContext,com.jc2.service.client.domobj.ClientDO,com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment.BaseContactMomentDo): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:390)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityOutflowInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityOutflowInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityDomainInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityDomainInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2EjbEAR-JC2Service.jar//com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment.ContactMomentFacade$$$view201.create(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.bean.page.client.contact.MaintainContactMomentBean.actionSave(MaintainContactMomentBean.java:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-4//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-4//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-4//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
    at javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.PDFRendererFilter.doFilter(PDFRendererFilter.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.PDFRendererFilter.doFilter(PDFRendererFilter.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.AggresiveExpiresFilter.doFilter(AggresiveExpiresFilter.java:28)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.SameSiteCookieFilter.doFilter(SameSiteCookieFilter.java:35)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.SameSiteCookieFilter.doFilter(SameSiteCookieFilter.java:35)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2Web.war//com.jc2.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:16)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.7.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a801fe:4ee973f3:6735b58f:5dd status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:279)
        ... 129 more
    Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a801fe:4ee973f3:6735b58f:5dd status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:98)
        ... 131 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:494)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:651)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//nl.lostlemon.mc.contactmoment.gen.api.DefaultApi.createContactMoment(DefaultApi.java:86)
    at deployment.JC2EjbEAR-8.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.JC2EjbEAR-JC2Service.jar//com.jc2.service.rest.contactmoment.ContactMomentFacadeBean.create(ContactMomentFacadeBean.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:302)
    ... 163 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:71)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 166 more


The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

" Suppressed: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447:" - that seems to be the key. Somewhere there is a persistence problem causing the transaction to be rolled back but whatever error handling is in place really does not handle that well causing errors to be stacked on top of errors. This is why debuggers exist, so you can step through the code and figure out where a problem starts.

What is DefaultApi? It appears to be making the REST call. How does it create the javax.ws.rs.client.Client?

I have the solution. While debugging It seemed that somewhere in the code the host and portnumber were not attached to the uri that was being called.
